# Which relational schema captures the semantics of this system

Tags: database, logic, schema, erd

me and my friend are arguing over what the correct answer for one of my questions, is. I have put A but he suggests that it may be B

**The question**

[image: Question]

[image]

Now this is why I believe I am correct, the third relationship, clearly models a M to M relationship, thus we would need to simplify it, therefore the "teaches" would become a entity in itself thus the correct answer would be **A**

I do not think it can be B or None of the Above.

Answer (score 0):

The semantics should be read: A course is taught by one lecturer, every lecturer is teaching one or more courses.

So, now, A) is M to M relation, so it's definitely out. To be a M to M, there should be arrows in both directions `Lecturer <- Teaches -> Course`

B is the answer since the class has the teacher as a foreign key